# Update yum offline

Tags: fedora, yum

I've been looking around for a way to update an offline fedora box but haven't found anything. I only have a Windows computer connected to the Internet. I noticed that my yum config is pointed to http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/updates/14/i386. Is there a way I can download a list of packages and then those packages manually but still use yum?

I've seen ways to do this with a second linux box that has Internet access, but I don't have that.

Comment: Could you run a virtual machine (say using VirtualBox) on your windows machine and do the downloading there? Meaning call `yum update`? You can probably copy the downloaded files there to your offline Fedora box. I'm not familar with how yum does it, but usually these package managers have a small list of files where they cache information.

Comment: That's a great idea. I didn't think of that.

Comment: ok, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Go to http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/publiclist/Fedora/14/ and choose a mirror near you.
2. Go to updates/14/i386/ and download everything using your favourite download manager/tool.
3. Copy everything to some media (e.g. USB key) and from that key to your Fedora 14 machine. For example you can make a /var/lib/yum/repo/F14_updates directory on your box.
4. Run `createrepo /path/to/your/downloaded/rpms`.
5. Add new repository description in /etc/yum.repos.d. Use some existing file as a template. The only change is the path: instead of http://... use file:///path/to/your/downloaded/rpms. Make sure to enable the repository.
6. Disable all other repositories -- you don't have access to them anyhow, so they won't help you.
7. Run `yum update` and enjoy your freshly updated system.

Answer (score 1):

You could run a virtual machine (say using VirtualBox) on your Windows machine and do the downloading there by calling `yum update`. You can then copy the downloaded files there to your offline Fedora box. I'm not familiar with how `yum` does it, but usually these package managers have a small list of files where they cache information.