# download software for later installation

Tags: linux

I know the way to install software on Linux i.e.

```
apt-get install
```

or

```
yum install
```

These methods will only works until we have internet connection. Is there any way, so that I can download the software from one PC with internet, then take that software to the other PC without internet & install the software there, as we can do it in Windows OS?

I tried manually downloading firefox browser from its website & then I extracted it, I got a single firefox. When I clicked on it, firefox directly open, but not installed.

Comment: You can create a local repository and use `apt-get` as you're used to. Example from the man page: `deb file:/home/jason/debian stable main` Or you can use `dpkg -i <package>` to install. This doesn't automatically resolve dependencies, though.

Comment: Also have a look at [apt-offline](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/648/Offline_Package_Management_for_APT).

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Ways to update Ubuntu (debian-based distros) offline](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89152/12779) or [Update yum offline](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/13347/12779)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Debian /Ubuntu you can use the command `apt-get download` (available from version 0.8.11 of apt). It doesn't download dependencies nor other packages, and it doesn't require root permissions.

The download *.deb file* is easily installed using dpkg, for example: `dpkg -i <deb file>`.

---

On CentOS/RHEL 7: 
`yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp <package-name>` will download the package to directory /tmp.
If the package has unmet dependencies, yum will download all dependent packages also, and none of them will be installed.

On CentOS/RHEL 6 or earlier, you have to previously install a plugin called *yum-plugin-downloadonly*  with the command `yum install yum-plugin-downloadonly`.

The downloaded *rpm file* can be installed with `rpm -Uvh rpm_file`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but you haven't mentioned how to install those downloaded packages after downloading.

Comment: *Is* there a way to download dependencies as well, on Ubuntu?

Comment: @Wilcard Check [this](http://superuser.com/questions/876727/how-to-download-deb-package-and-all-dependencies) answer. It's a better answer than mine and includes the way to download the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [jcbermu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/236023/135943), on CentOS/RHEL 6, you don't need to install any plugins; just use `yumdownloader`.  From the man page, excerpted:

```
NAME
       yumdownloader

SYNOPSIS
       yumdownloader [options] package1 [package2...]

DESCRIPTION
       yumdownloader  is a program for downloading RPMs from Yum repositories.


GENERAL OPTIONS
       ...

       --destdir DIR
              Specify a destination directory for the download.   Defaults  to
              the current directory.

       ...

       --resolve
              When downloading RPMs, resolve dependencies  and  also  download
              the required packages.
```

So all you need for the simple case is `yumdownloader --destdir /tmp --resolve somepackage`.