# Problem in installing new software - RHEL6

Tags: linux, rhel, download

I am currently having difficulty in installing new software/plugins on my rhel6 work pc. I don't have any internet connection on it and have to download anything I require on a separate internet PC (ubuntu).

Hence I always end up scouring for rpms to install (most of the time, RPM find links dont work for me either). I was wondering if there was a possibility to go have a round about way for it?

I was going through : [download software for later installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/236002/download-software-for-later-installation). I wanted to know if I can masquerade my ubuntu as a rhel /centos pc and download the package.

---

Secondly, I am quite new to using linux and cant understand how to use source-forge links and ftp links.

I have given up on using source code as I nearly always lack the dependencies. A manager of mine recommended me to use .rpms as they are per-compiled ?

I would love some information regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three possibilities here. Since you don't want to compile from source there are two remains:

- CentOS packages *should* work for rhel. At least it always worked for my rhel6.6. So you can download desired rpm from [centos repo](http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/) to your ubuntu then copy to rhel and install
- Using ubuntu's package manager download .deb package and then convert deb->rpm using [alien](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/11/alien-command-examples/)

Also you can try less obvious things like using your ubuntu as gateway/proxy/vpn for your rhel, but this method depends from your network topology and has much less chances to solve your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
createrepo path/of/folder/where/your/rpmStore
```

then run this command

remove the repo file

```
rm -iv  /etc/yu.repos.d/*
```

then create own repo file

```
echo -e "[MyRepo] \n name=MyRepo \n baseurl=file:/path/of/folder/where/your/rpmStore \n enabled=1 \n gpgcheck=0 \n skip_if_unavailable=True">/etc/yum.repos.d/myrepo.repo
```

it look like
[image]

after that

```
yum clean all
```

and then install software that you have in that folder ex:

```
yum install gedit -y
```